# Подскажите скрипт для обрезки изображения автоматом (при загрузке страницы)?

Tags: php, изображения

Пример - есть картинка 1000х1000 в каталоге image, нужно ее обрезать до 800x400
и поместить в папку image_crop.

Обрезка должна проходить по системе - уменьшить ширину до 800 (станет 800х800) и потом обрезать по 200 снизу и сверху что бы вышло 800х400

Помогите примером кода или ссылками на готовые решения.

Comment: картинку надо обрезать или масштабировать?

Comment: точно исходные изображения всегда квадратные?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так (не проверял):

```
<?php

/**
 * имя запрошенного файла в GET-параметре image:
 * script.php?image=apple.jpg
 */

define( 'IMG_SRC_PATH', '/var/www/mysite/image');
define( 'IMG_CROPPED_PATH', '/var/www/mysite/image_crop');

$filename = $_GET['image']; // TODO: проверить на существование, непустоту, очистить от "../.." и спецсимволов

$srcFile = IMG_SRC_PATH . '/' . $filename;
$dstFile = IMG_CROPPED_PATH . '/' . $filename;

if( file_exists( $dstFile)) {
    // уже есть переделанная картинка, отдаём её
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    readfile( $dstFile);
    exit();
}

if(!file_exists( $srcFile)) {
    header('Not found', true, 404);
    echo "File not found: " . htmlspecialchars( $srcFile);
    exit();
}

list( $width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize( $srcFile);


switch( $type) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        $imagedata = imagecreatefromgif( $srcFile);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG2000:
        $imagedata = imagecreatefromjpeg( $srcFile);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        $imagedata = imagecreatefrompng( $srcFile);
        break;
    default:
        $imagedata = false;
}

if( false === $imagedata) {
    header('Bad image type', true, 500);
    echo "Image type not supported: " . $type;
    exit();
}

// Resize the image
$thumbW = 800;
$thumbH = 400;
$proportion = $thumbW / $thumbH;
$k = $width / $height;

$thumbdata = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumbW, $thumbH);
imagefill( $thumbdata, 0, 0, 0xFFFFFF);

if( $k > $proportion) {
    // fit height, crop on left/right sides
    $scale = $thumbH / $height;

    $srcW = $height * $proportion;
    $srcH = $height;

    $srcX = ( $width - $thumbW / $scale) / 2;
    $srcY = 0;
} else {
    // fit width, crop on top/bottom
    $scale = $thumbW / $width;

    $srcW = $width;
    $srcH = $height / $proportion;

    $srcX = 0;
    $srcY = ( $height - $thumbH / $scale) / 2;
}

imagecopyresampled( $thumbdata, $imagedata, 0, 0, $srcX, $srcY, $thumbW, $thumbH, $srcW, $srcH);

imagejpeg( $thumbdata, $dstFile);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile( $dstFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
$filename= "test.jpg";
list($w, $h, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($filename);
$src_im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$src_x = '0';   // начальная позиция x
$src_y = '0';   // начальная позиция y
$src_w = '100'; // ширина
$src_h = '100'; // высота
$dst_x = '0';   // координата результирующего изображения x
$dst_y = '0';   // координата результирующего изображения y
$dst_im = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h);
$white = imagecolorallocate($dst_im, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($dst_im, 0, 0, $white);
imagecopy($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($dst_im);
imagedestroy($dst_im);
?>
```

давно я это делал , но код был мною проверен но давненько

Comment: удалите - это я у себя делал (давно) по ошибке скопировал

Answer (score 0):

Я использую это библиотеку. Работает на ура.
https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage